# Auth0 - Why do they want users to use a WebView over getting Strings from an EditText to authenticate?

Tags: android, auth0

I'm trying to implement Auth0 into a mobile application. I have used a managed authentication service like AWS cognito before where the SDK lets you get the typed email/password from the edittext to authenticate. However I'm confused about Auth0 because it has a thing called a "Universal Login".

On their docs it says

```
 "Auth0 encourages the use of web authentication via Universal Login 
  rather than native username/password authentication whenever possible."
```

https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock-android/v2

Why do they want users to use a webview over the native get the Strings from the EditTexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already have some answers under [this link](https://auth0.com/docs/guides/login/universal-vs-embedded#pros-and-cons) - Pros and Cons section

implementing web sheet will provide consistency across all apps and even devices, which will get you a little more log-ins (people will sooner pick familiar method). this web form will be maintained by 0auth devs, so it will be secure and up-to-date always (you don't have to worry as developer). also "custom" `EditText`s may allow you to steal entered password in a very easy way, even devs aren't trust-worth (users perspective). at the end I would add cookie feature, which will keep your session, so you won't have to handle by itself

in short: web form is just for easing your and users life - you don't have to maintain much code and user gets familiar and trustful method of log in

PS. technically there is no difference between native and web log-in, as long as developer won't try to manipulate with this mechanism